# How to get the current real-time log data from log4js？

Tags: node.js, log4js-node

I have a requirement now, when log4js is printing logs, I need to get the current real-time log data, a complete piece of log information (log4js processed).Does log4js has such an interface?

`logger.error("Cheese is too ripe!");`

When the code is executed，I get

`[2020-07-15T11:19:07.452] [ERROR] cheese - Cheese is too ripe!`

How can I get this whole string from log4js in my code rather than 'Cheese is too ripe'

Answer (score 0):

I just find a way to solve it by use recording appender.
Use replay and layout method to make the same log sentence.